# Bug em app algorithmia

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando rodar o seguinte código:

```
const  algorithmia = require("algorithmia");

function trigger() {
  const  url = {"url": "https://www.facebook.com/filipedeschamps?epa=SEARCH_BOX"}
  const apiKey = "sim7psIeBatrvpJajm3Dw3uN1hq1"


  const randomTextAuthenticate = algorithmia(apiKey)

  const randomText = randomTextAuthenticate.algo("koverholt/randomtext/0.1.0")

  const randomTextResponse = randomText.pipe(url)

  console.log(randomTextResponse)

  const randomTextResult = randomTextResponse.get()
}

console.log(trigger())
```

Mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> TypeError: randomTextResponse.get is not a function
> at trigger (/home/romis/olavoTrigger/index.js:17:46)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/home/romis/olavoTrigger/index.js:21:13)
> at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
> at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
> at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação disponibilizada pela Algorithmia](https://algorithmia.com/developers/clients/node/), o método `pipe` retorna uma `Promise`. Desse modo, você precisa encadeá-lo em uma cadeia de `Promise`s:

```
const algorithmia = require('algorithmia')

function trigger() {
  const url = { url: 'https://www.facebook.com/filipedeschamps?epa=SEARCH_BOX' }
  const apiKey = 'sim7psIeBatrvpJajm3Dw3uN1hq1'

  const randomTextAuthenticate = algorithmia(apiKey)
  const randomText = randomTextAuthenticate.algo('koverholt/randomtext/0.1.0')

  // Note abaixo que encadeamos o método `then` após o método `pipe`:
  randomText.pipe(url).then((randomTextResult) => {
    const randomTextResult = randomTextResult.get()
    console.log(randomTextResult)
  })
}

trigger()
```

Note que, se você desejar, você também pode abordar esse problema usando `async`/`await`:

```
const algorithmia = require('algorithmia')

async function trigger() {
  const url = { url: 'https://www.facebook.com/filipedeschamps?epa=SEARCH_BOX' }
  const apiKey = 'sim7psIeBatrvpJajm3Dw3uN1hq1'

  const randomTextAuthenticate = algorithmia(apiKey)
  const randomText = randomTextAuthenticate.algo('koverholt/randomtext/0.1.0')

  // Note abaixo que usamos a palavra-chave `await` para aguardar a resolução da Promise:
  const randomTextResult = await randomText.pipe(url)

  // Como a Promise foi resolvida, você pode usar o método `get` diretamente:
  const randomTextResult = randomTextResult.get()
  console.log(randomTextResult)
}

trigger()
```

#### Abordagem em vídeo:

Note que esse problema foi abordado no vídeo do Filipe. Você pode ver o trecho [aqui](https://youtu.be/8XgbjUP-Gxo?t=643).

#### Referência:

- [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise);
- [Uma introdução a `Promise`s](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises);
- [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou!

Comment: Nesse caso, marque essa resposta como a solução da pergunta clicando no ícone ✔︎ no canto superior esquerdo da postagem. :)